# R - streamline subsampling procedure

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataset composed of values obtained from studies and experiments. Experiments are nested within studies. I want to subsample the dataset so that only 1 experiment is represented for each study. I want to repeat this procedure 10,000 times, randomly drawing the 1 experiment each time, and then calculate some summary statistics for the values.  Here is an example dataset:

```
df=data.frame(study=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4),expt=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2),value=runif(8))
```

I wrote the following function to do the above, but it is taking forever. Does anyone have any suggestions for streamlining this code? Thanks!

```
subsample=function(x,A) {
  subsample.list=sapply(1:A,function(m) {
    idx=ddply(x,c("study"),function(i) sample(1:nrow(i),1)) #Sample one experiment from each study
    x[paste(x$study,x$expt,sep="-") %in% paste(idx$study,idx$V1,sep="-"),"value"] } ) #Match the study-experiment combinations and retrieve values
  means.list=ldply(subsample.list,mean) #Calculate the mean of 'values' for each iteration
  c(quantile(means.list$V1,0.025),mean(means.list$V1),upper=quantile(means.list$V1,0.975)) } #Calculate overall means and 95% CIs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorise this way more (even using plyr), and go much much faster:

```
function=yoursummary(x)c(quantile(x,0.025),mean(x),upper=quantile(x,0.975))
subsampleX=function(x,M)
  yoursummary(
    aaply(
      daply(.drop_o=F,df,.(study),
        function(x)sample(x$value,M,replace=T)
      ),1,mean
    )
  )
```

The trick here is to do all the sampling up front.  If we want to sample M times, why not do all that while you have access to the study.

### Original code:

```
> system.time(subsample(df,20000))
   user  system elapsed 
 123.23    0.06  124.74
```

### New vectorised code:

```
> system.time(subsampleX(df,20000))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.24    0.00    0.25
```

That's about 500x faster.

Comment: Did you mean `ddply(df,.(study),function(i) i[sample(1:nrow(i),1),])` ?

Comment: Yes. Editing on my phone is fiddly.

Comment: Fixed for you.  I'm impressed.  I feel accomplished when I code on my iPad, nevermind my phone!

Comment: Ah-ha, I see what you did here. Very clever!

Comment: Also I was having trouble with `aaply` kicking back `NAs` with my dataset.  I substituted `ddply` and used `colMeans` instead of `aaply`.  Its 4x slower but still a hell of a lot faster than my old method!

Comment: Depending upon your data set size you may want to chunk this up to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example Of the NA problem?

Comment: Ah I found the problem.  In my dataframe, study and experiment were both factors. When I subset a portion of my original dataset, I didn't use `droplevels` and the extra levels of the factors were showing up as NAs.

Comment: There's a flag or that in aaply: probably .i_drop=T

Comment: Great thanks. I just used `droplevels(x)`.  Appreciate the replies, especially from your phone!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution which avoids ddply for speed reasons:

```
df=data.frame(study=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4),expt=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2),value=runif(8))

sample.experiments <- function(df) {
    r <- rle(df$study)
    samp <- sapply( r$lengths , function(x) sample(seq(x),1) )
    start.idx <- c(0,cumsum(r$lengths)[1:(length(r$lengths)-1)] )
    df[samp + start.idx,]
}
> sample.experiments(df)
  study expt     value
1     1    1 0.6113196
4     2    2 0.5026527
6     3    1 0.2803080
7     4    1 0.9824377
```

**Benchmarks**

```
> m <- microbenchmark(
+   ddply(df,.(study),function(i) i[sample(1:nrow(i),1),]) ,
+   sample.experiments(df)
+   )
> m
Unit: microseconds
                                                        expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1 ddply(df, .(study), function(i) i[sample(1:nrow(i), 1), ]) 3808.652 3883.632 3936.805 4022.725 6530.506
2                                     sample.experiments(df)  337.327  350.734  357.644  365.915  580.097
```

[image: autoplot microbenchmark]